# AWK output every 1GB instead of 100,000 rows

Tags: unix, awk

I have a 42 GB / 6.2 million rows xml file that I'm trying to break down into manageable sizes (they have to be less than 1 GB). At the moment I have a process that is building a new file every 100,000 rows and it works, but it's generating 62 files that have a high amount of variance in the file size - ranging from 600 MB to 1100 MB.

If I can rewrite the script to work with a size limit, I should have to process less files on my following steps.

Every row starts with `<ent>` and ends with `</ent>`.

Is there a way that I can modify this script to output a new file every 900 MB rather than 100,000 rows?

This is the script I have now. Please note that i don't particularly understand all of this and I've got to this point through google and trial and error.

```
BEGIN { new_chunk = 1 ; size = 100000 }

NR == 1 { header = $0 ; footer = "</" substr($1,2) ">" ; next }

$0 !~ footer {
  if (new_chunk) {
    outfile = "ent_" sprintf("%07d", num) ".xml"
    print header > outfile
    new_chunk = 0
  }
print > outfile
}

/<ent>/ {
  num = int(count++/size)
  if (num > prev_num) {
    print footer > outfile
    new_chunk = 1
  }
prev_num = num
}

END { if (!new_chunk) print footer > outfile }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: `man split` may help  .. then feed it to  xargs or parallel

Comment: You can use `chars += length($0)` to accumulate the number of characters and start a new chunk when it exceeds your threshold. This may be approximate if there are multibyte characters in the data, depending on how your version of awk implements `length()`.

Comment: When you say `Every row starts with <ent> and ends with </ent>.` - what does the term `row` mean to you? I assume it's not just a line of text since lines simply end in `\n`. Given that, should your files be allowed to start/end mid-`row`? Please post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

OP hasn't provided a sample input file so reverse engineering bits-n-pieces of OP's current code I came up with this (bogus) file for demonstration purposes:

```
$ cat input.xml
<some header record>
<ent> line1 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line2 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line3 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line4 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line5 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line6 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line7 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line8 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
</some>
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v maxsize='250' '                                 # replace "250" with max file size

function switch_file(op) {
    if (outfile)
       print footer > outfile
    close(outfile)
    if (op != "end") {                                 # if op == "end" do not bother with creating a new file
       outfile="ent_" sprintf("%07d",++c) ".xml"
       print header > outfile
       size=len_hdr
    }
}

NR==1   { header=$0
          len_hdr=length(header)+1                     # "+1" for trailing "\n"
          footer="</" substr($1,2) ">"
          len_ftr=length(footer)+1                     # "+1" for trailing "\n"
          switch_file()
        }

/<ent>/ { len_curr=length($0)+1                        # "+1" for trailing "\n"
          if (size + len_curr + len_ftr > maxsize)
             switch_file()
          print $0 > outfile
          size+=len_curr
        }

END     { switch_file("end") }                         # terminate the current outfile

' input.xml
```

**NOTE:** as mentioned in a comment the `length()` function returns number of characters (not number of bytes) so if the input file has multi-byte characters this code is going to undercount the number of bytes; handling multi-byte characters is doable in `awk` but requires a bit more coding and/or an extension

This generates:

```
$ head ent_*xml
==> ent_0000001.xml <==
<some header record>
<ent> line1 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line2 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line3 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
</some>

==> ent_0000002.xml <==
<some header record>
<ent> line4 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line5 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line6 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
</some>

==> ent_0000003.xml <==
<some header record>
<ent> line7 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
<ent> line8 : 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</ent>
</some>

$ wc ent_*xml
  5  16 242 ent_0000001.xml          # total size(242) < 250
  5  16 242 ent_0000002.xml          # total size(242) < 250
  4  12 171 ent_0000003.xml          # total size(171) < 250
 14  44 655 total
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count ***chars AND bytes*** in `gawk`'s `Unicode mode (UTF-8)` :

- counting bytes w/o altering locale settings

> ```
>  match(str, /$/) - 1
> ```

- counting `UTF-8` characters for spec-compliant text input

> ```
>  length(str)
> ```

- safely counting `UTF-8` characters for `binary / non-UTF8 / corrupted` input w/o triggering warning messages

> ```
>  gsub(/./, "&", str)
> ```

*(it works for the most part, but `gawk 5.2.2` still mis-counts by single digits % this way due to unknown bug(s). For now, in order to obtain an ***EXACT*** count w/o warnings and/or error msgs, a tedious workaround of splitting the same-string into an array ***TWICE*** using different `regex` is needed) :*

---

```
        split(str, arr,  ""  ) - (\
(arrL = split(str, arr, ".*")) - (arr[1] == "") - (arr[arrL] == ""))
```

---

e.g.

```
printf '%s' 'AU+4aU+6U+39U+39!U+2ØU+D8ڃU+683U+C9AU+27EU+F6' | 

gwc -lcm

  0      47      55
```

---

```
gawk -e '{ print OFS = "\t", __ =  (RT != (_ = "")), 
                             __ + length($(_ = +_)), 
                             __ +  match( $_, /$/) - !_ }' 
  0    47    55
```

Output matches that of `gnu-wc`. Exact hex of that string (from `xxd`) ::

```
41552b3461552b36552b3339552b333921552b32c398552b4438da83552b
363833552b433941f0a09c8e552b323745f09f9881552b4636
```